# Ruby on rails pass value of hyper link from link_to tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following code in my view:

```
<%= form_for :command_selected, :method => "get", :url => {:action => "command_domain_selected"} do |f| %>

<a> <%= link_to "Make Deployment",  {:controller=>"authorization",  :action => 'command_domain_selected',:id=>'make_deployment'}, :remote=> true %><br /></a>


 <%= f.radio_button :domain, '1dev' %> <%= label :domain, '1dev'%><br />
 <%= f.radio_button :domain, '2dev' %> <%= label :domain, '2dev'%><br />

<script type=text/javascript>
$('a').click(function(){     $('form').submit();     return false; }); 
</script>

<%end%>
```

When i click on the "`Make Deployment`" link in the above code, only the `selected radio button` is passed as the parameter to the `command_domain_selected` action in the controller. Please let me know how to pass the value of the `hyperlink` too.
Thank you

I added the following code too:

```
<%= link_to 'Make Deployment', "#", :onclick=>"$('.search_form').submit()" , :id => 'make_deployment'%>
```

But the parameters that are being passed are just the radio button values and not the hyperlink value

Comment: You have some horrible code there, don't you? Why haven't you done `<%= form_for :command_selected, :method => "get", :url => {:action => "command_domain_selected"}, :remote => true do |f| %>` and only created a `<%= f.submit %>`? This script is absolutely useless.

Comment: @YuriAlbuquerque  I could have used f.submit but i do not want to have a submit button. I would like to have just a hypelink that says "make deployment" and when we select a radio button and click on the link, i want it to pass the hyperlink value and radio button to the controller. I think this is possible seeing some posts like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791538/rails-3-submit-form-with-link) but iam not able to pass the value of hyperlink in the params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with Yuri. Use a form (method get and it will all go in the URL). Then just style the button to look like a link if you're that fussed!

Otherwise if you must continue with the hideousness add a hidden_field with the extra param you want to submit. Its not passing the hyperlink params because that has nothing to do with a form (unlike a submit button which does)