# Ruby on Rails submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, web

How can I change submit button on form to text?

```
<%= f.submit "Text" %>
```

I know how to change text on button but I need to change a way to submitting. 
You can press on link, for example Submit and submit.

Comment: Are you saying you want to use a link to submit instead of a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the submitting of a form to be triggered by a link as opposed to a submit button, you must use javascript instead of raw generated HTML only.

See [similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791538/rails-3-submit-form-with-link) on StackOverflow but a summary of a possible solution in jQuery (which comes baked into recent versions of Rails) would be as follows:

```
$('#submit_link').click(function(){
    $('form').submit();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what ruby version you are using. But try this

```
<%= submit_tag "Text" %>
```

Note that there is no form helper here, so no "f." in front

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: This should do it using HAML notation in Rails 2.3.x:

```
- form_for(@object) do |f|
  = f.submit 'Update Or Whatever'
```

You could also try "button" tag or use an image link that looks like a button.