# Rails - Form_For Submit using a Link and not a Button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

For my rails application, I am using a form_for to submit form and was wondering how I would adjust it so that it is using a link and not a button to submit just this form alone and not the other forms in my application.  I have referenced the posting here ([Rails 3 submit form with link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791538/rails-3-submit-form-with-link)) but where do I put the `link_to` companion link?

`companion link: link_to 'submit me', '#', :class => 'submit_me'`

_view.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(current_user.likes.build(blog_id: blog.id)) do |f| %>
     <div><%= f.hidden_field :blog_id %></div>
     <%= f.submit "SUBMIT" %>
<% end %>
```

.js

```
$('.submit_me').click(function() {
  $('form').submit();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: two questions: 1. WHY ?
2. Would it be enough to make the button LOOK like a normal link?

Comment: You should not do this, it's bad practice, except if you for some reason have to submit the form from somewhere outside of the form... But use the id of the form to get the right form like `$('#id-of-my-form').submit();`.

Comment: If I want it to look like a normal link, what is best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plop this in your application helper

```
def link_to_submit(*args, &block)
  link_to_function (block_given? ? capture(&block) : args[0]), "$(this).closest('form').submit()", args.extract_options!
end
```

And then you can generate links in your views as follows:

```
<%= link_to_submit 'Submit Form' %>
```

Comment: That does work and change it to a link, but when I apply a css class on it for a link, it doesn't change it. Do you know why? <%= link_to_submit 'Submit', class: "link" %>

Comment: Please accept my answer if you would be so kind. `<%= link_to_submit 'Submit', html: { class: "link" } %>`

Comment: Best practice would be to just style the submit button to look like a link using CSS